# Snackbar callback onDismiss() called first

Tags: android, callback, listener, snackbar

I have defined the call back for handling `snackbar` `dismiss()` and `show()`.

```
   Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
   View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
   snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 8, 20, 37));
   snackbar.setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
                    super.onShown(snackbar);
                    Debug.e(TAG, "Shown");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                    super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
                    Debug.e(TAG, "Dismissed");
                }
            });
            snackbar.show();
```

But when I check my Logcat the `onDismiss()` is calling before `onShown()`

```
 12-31 12:36:29.601 2883-2883/BaseFragment: Dismissed
 12-31 12:36:29.880 2883-2883/BaseFragment:    Shown
```

So am I doing something wrong? Any Idea?

Comment: I tested that works fine :)

Comment: what is the design library version?

Comment: Support design library version is 23.4.0

Comment: @Jaymin Panchal so you dont get any visual of it?

Comment: Are you trying to show it multiple times quickly?

Comment: what is Debug. e <- Why don't you use `Log.d`

Comment: If the tags are same, why "Shown" in the log is much **center** while Dismissed starts in left ? see mine https://i.stack.imgur.com/wweyH.png

Comment: @Charuka I have created a wrapper class of Log to manage all the Log things.

Comment: @srijith no It is called only once.

Comment: @Jaymin Panchal so snack bar is not displayed right?

Comment: @Charuka Snackbar is displaying but onDimiss() is called first every time so my all related logic goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

It might be because another snack bar is replacing this one. In such a case, `onDismissed()` will be called for the earlier one and `onShown()` for the new one. In your logs, you should also see which snack bar each method is being called for. You may also check the event for which `onDismissed()` is called. If it is 4, it means it has been dismissed due to being replaced with another snack bar.
Hope it helps!